# Can Ted Cruz and John Kasich still win delegates in upcoming 2016 state primaries?

Tags: united-states, republican-primary

Ted Cruz and John Kasich, like many Republican candidates before them, have suspended their presidential campaigns this week.

I'm curious about the upcoming state primaries.  Will they still be on the ballots?  Is it still theoretically possible that they could win additional delegates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for any candidate on the ballots of the remaining primaries to gain delegates. In most states, once you are on the ballot, you are on the ballot. It would be too much of a PITA for the states to take them off. Notice that Cruz did not withdraw; he suspended his campaign.